# ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments when using NVL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column that gets the specific amount which has a condition like below.

I tried this one to get his specific value but I getting a multiple rows which it should be single row.

```
select distinct
(case 
    when aila.line_type_lookup_code = 'ITEM' and aila.tax_classification_code = 'VAT12 SERVICES' then to_char(aila.assessable_value) else '0'
end) as taxable_lines
from
ap_invoice_lines_all aila

where
aila.invoice_id = '31004'
```

then I tried this one to replace a null values.

```
select distinct
(case
    when aila.line_type_lookup_code = 'ITEM' and aila.tax_classification_code = 'VAT12 SERVICES' then nvl(to_char(aila.assessable_value,0)) end) as taxable_lines

from
ap_invoice_lines_all aila

where
aila.invoice_id = '31004'
```

For example I have a table named ap_invoice_lines_all that has a columns name

```
line_type_lookup_code   string
tax_classification_code  string
assessable_value         double
```

then the expected output I want based on the query I tried above is

```
taxable lines
1300
```

but the one I get is

```
taxable lines
0
1300
```

How do I remove the 0 in the result?
Thanks!

Comment: The problem is not the case, but your select.
if there are two records in the table with `invoice_id = '31004'` then you will get two rows as a result.

Comment: `nvl` Need always 2 Parameters `NVL( string1, replace_with )`

Comment: Hi @hotfix When I tried to select the condition, it only turns 1 row. But I need to do this as subquery for a condition.

Comment: I tried the NVL(assessable_value, 0) but I got the error invalid number of arguments

Comment: how many rows do you get`select * from.. where aila.invoice_id = '31004'` ?
 you get invalid number  exception because your Parameters have not the same type

Comment: I only got 1 row. My data type for the column ```assessable_value``` is double so I convert it into char,

Comment: Can you provide the data, or example data, that you have in the table? Maybe create an http://www.sqlfiddle.com and share it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you are using `to_char` wrong. This function should only have a single argument in this context:

`nvl(to_char(aila.assessable_value,0))`

should be

`nvl(to_char(aila.assessable_value),0)`

I would recommend against using a case expression like this in such a simple query to improve readability. Case expressions are great tools, but typically decrease the query readability. And in this particular instance, you don't really need an IF..THEN..ELSE function (which is the reason to use case expressions).

Secondly, are you sure there is only record where `aila.invoice_id = '31004'`? The query will only return two rows if there are actually two rows in the table where that clause is true. In this case it finds one row where `assessable_value` is null and one where it isn't.

In any case, to remove the zero (or in this case a null value) from the resultset, you can simply do this:

```
select distinct aila.assessable_value as taxable_lines
from   ap_invoice_lines_all aila
where  aila.invoice_id              = '31004'
and    aila.line_type_lookup_code   = 'ITEM'           -- Originally a condition in the case statement
and    aila.tax_classification_code = 'VAT12 SERVICES' -- Originally a condition in the case statement
and    aila.assessable_value is not null;              -- Removes any null values from the result
```

Or if you want null values to be replaced by a zero;

```
select distinct nvl(aila.assessable_value, 0) as taxable_lines 
from   ap_invoice_lines_all aila
where  aila.invoice_id              = '31004'
and    aila.line_type_lookup_code   = 'ITEM'           -- Originally a condition in the case statement
and    aila.tax_classification_code = 'VAT12 SERVICES' -- Originally a condition in the case statement
```

Note that the `distinct` clause will cause all rows where `assessable_value` to be grouped into a single row if multiple rows are a possibility. Remove the `distinct` clause if you want all rows where `assessable_value` is null to show in the result as `0`.

Lastly, you might want to think about implementing a primary key (if the table doesn't have one) or unique index on `invoice_id`, if there shouldn't ever be duplicate ids. And it's simply good practice to do so for ID columns which are used often in queries and should be unique.